# Why are function dependencies treated differently than other dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

If I have: `useCallback(() => setData(props.data), [])`

then exhaustive deps will ask me to add ***props.data*** to dependencies.

However if I have: `useCallback(() => setData(props.getData()), [])`

then exhaustive deps will ask me to add ***props*** to dependencies, and also tell me I should destructure it instead because props will change every render.

So my question is why can't I just add ***props.getData*** to my dependencies if it works for non function props?

Comment: I don't know the details of the rules, but when you call a function as a "method", which is what `props.getData()` is doing, then `getData` has access to `props` via `this`. That means, `props.getData`, the function, may not change, but `props` might and thus the result of calling the function could differ, even if the function itself doesn't change.

Comment: @FelixKling So then a destructured function (const getData = props.getData) would no longer be tied to the same "this" from props?
Or would it be tied to that particular version of props forever?

Comment: If it was an ordinary function at the first place (not an arrow function), then it will see `this === undefined`, unless you set it explicitly with `bind`, `call` or `apply`.

Answer (score 1):

This might be how JavaScript allocates memory.

When you create a variable e.g. `const x = 'myString'` JavaScript will allocate memory for a string, it does things differently for objects, numbers and for functions these are treated as 'callable objects'.

So by deconstructing the props.getData to `const { getData } = props`, what you're doing is creating a new pointer for getData, which means adding it as a dependency it will be treated independently from props.